# get a handle in ssjs to sortable column view

Tags: xpages

I have a view that has a column to make it sortable.
When clicking on the column header the view will be sorted ascending /descending.
How can I get a handle to this sorting in SSJS , I mean how can I sort it using SSJS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a view as a data source there are 2 properties.

1. sortColumn - column to sort by
2. sortOrder  - which order to sort by

You could compute these with scoped variables and refresh, that should do it

Comment: Do you mean define the view as datasource in SSJS ? Could you give a small example ?

Comment: no, in the xpages source. Take for example a dataview control, you would have <xe:dataview> <xe:this.data> <xp:dominoView viewName="..." sortColumn="#{viewScope.dataviewSortColumn}"></xp:dominoView> </xe:this.data> </xe:dataview>. Now by modifying viewScope.dataviewSortColumn in SSJS you can change the sorting column and the same with sortOrder